# Get even numbers from string and sum

Tags: haskell

I need to find all even numbers from `String` input.

I managed to get all even numbers to list, but I don't understand excactly how can I get sum of those even numbers afterwards.

```
numbers :: String -> [Int]
numbers [] = []
numbers (l:ls) = if ord l == 48 || ord l == 50 || ord l == 52 || ord l == 54 || ord l == 56
    then (ord l - 48): (numbers ls)
    else (numbers ls)
```

So the result would be something like: "abc1234" => 6

Comment: Haskell has a `sum` function. If you have the even numbers (and not the string representation of those numbers) in a list, just sum the list. I fail to see why this is a problem. Surely you have seen how to sum lists. Typically, one of the very first examples you will see of a recursive function definition in Haskell is one which sums lists (if you don't want to use the built-in `sum`).

Comment: You are also reimplementing the `filter` function.

Answer (score 2):

You're already pretty there. `(ord l - 48)` extracts the integer value from the string, so you have to accumulate this value. Or sum up the resulting result (which is basically a function)

The basic recursive loop would be:

```
numbers :: String -> Int -> Int
Given an empty string and accumulated value -> return accumulated value
Given string (l:ls) not empty and accumulated value ->
    if l matches your criteria
           numbers ls (accumulated value + (ord l - 48))
    else 
           numbers ls (solely the accumulated value, as `l` doesn't match criteria)
```

Answer (score 2):

another alternative to write the same

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

sumEvens = sum . map digitToInt . filter (`elem` "2468")
```